# Executing powershell command directly in jenkins pipeline

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to call a PowerShell command directly in the pipelines groovy script? While using custom jobs in Jenkins I am able to call the command with the PowerShell Plugin. But there is no snippet to use this in the groovy script.

I also tried `sh()` but it seems that this command does not allow multiple lines and comments inside the command.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To call a PowerShell script from the Groovy-Script:

- you have to use the `bat` command.
- After that, you have to be sure that the Error Code (`errorlevel`) variable will be correctly returned (`EXIT 1` should resulting in a `FAILED` job).
- Last, to be compatible with the PowerShell-Plugin, you have to be sure that `$LastExitCode` will be considered.
- I have notice that the 'powershell' is now available in pipeline, but since it have several issues I prefer this variant. Still waiting it works stabil. I actually have an issue with the 'dontKillMe' behavior.

> Since Jenkins 2.207 with Powershell plugin 1.4, I have replace all my calls with the official powershell pipeline command. I do now recommend to use it.
> Note that you must predent `\$ErrorActionPreference='Stop';` to your Script if you want it to abort on Write-Error because of [an Issue with the powershell plugin](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-36002).

For that porpuse I have written a little groovy method which could be integrate in any pipeline-script:

```
def PowerShell(psCmd) {
    psCmd=psCmd.replaceAll("%", "%%")
    bat "powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command \"\$ErrorActionPreference='Stop';[Console]::OutputEncoding=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8;$psCmd;EXIT \$global:LastExitCode\""
}
```

*[EDIT] I have added the UTF8 OutputEncoding: works great with Server 2016 and Win10.[/EDIT]*
*[EDIT] I have added the '%' mask[/EDIT]*

In your Pipeline-Script you could then call your Script like this:

```
stage ('Call Powershell Script')
{
    node ('MyWindowsSlave') {
        PowerShell(". '.\\disk-usage.ps1'") 
    }
}
```

The best thing with that method, is that you may call `CmdLet` without having to do this in the Script, which is best-praxis.

Call ps1 to define `CmdLet`, an then call the `CmdLet`

```
PowerShell(". '.\\disk-usage.ps1'; du -Verbose")
```

- Do not forget to use [withEnv()](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/top-10-best-practices-jenkins-pipeline-plugin) an then you are better than fully compatible with the Powershell plugin.
- postpone your Script with `.` to be sure your step failed when the script return an error code (should be preferred), use `&` if you don't care about it.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's helped me out a lot. How would you escape " in the command so that it shows up properly? For example, passing: .Split(":") results in the command being evaluated as .Split(:)

Comment: `"` should be masked for groovy and batch: `PowerShell("Write-Output \\\"hereXamXI\\\".Split(\\\"X\\\")")` do the thing for me. I prefer to replace `"` by `'`: `PowerShell("Write-Output 'hereXamXI'.Split('X')")`. Regards

Comment: Is there a trick to getting arguments for CmdLet working with this solution?

Comment: @Naxin you have several ways to bypass Parameters:
(1) Use [Groovy substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572080/how-to-access-parameters-in-a-parameterized-build) with ${PIPELINE_VAR} (be carefull with spaces) (2) Use [Powershell susbstitution with environment variables](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#withenv-set-environment-variables) (be carefull with masking $). Note this also apply to the native powershell command.

Answer (score 29):

Calling PowerShell scripts is now supported with `powershell` step as announced on [Jenkins blog](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/07/26/powershell-pipeline/).

The [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-powershell-code-powershell-script) mentions it supports multiple lines scripts.

Comment: Hi, not sure if I'm a bit late on this issue, I noticed that the powershell support by default use the -NoProfile plugin, do you know is there a way around this? I can't seem to run my pipeline as I need access to the powershell profile.

Comment: How to run a PowerShell script file .ps1 using the `powershell` step?

Answer (score 2):

From version 2.28 of Pipeline Nodes and Processes Plugin, we can directly use 'powershell'.

```
Eg: powershell(". '.Test.ps1'")
```

Answer (score -9):

You can use the `sh` command like this:

```
sh """
    echo 'foo'
    # bar
    echo 'hello'
"""
```

Comments are supported in here.

Comment: that works on one of my windows nodes but not the other.  Is there something you need to do to the OS to enable it?

Comment: the sh command will start a bash session, also with windows slave, which is not a PowerShell environment.
You can try `sh 'where ps.exe'` or `sh 'echo $SHELL'` in your Pipeline.
See : [link](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-sh-code-shell-script)
Note that `ps.exe`must be install on the windows slave.