# Running Powershell script in Jenkins Declarative pipeline

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I want to run Powershell script on agent from Jenkins declarative pipeline. It hangs on the script execution step (click on Job logs) and i have to forcefully exit it. What is the correct way to execute powershell script from pipeline and also so that it show output in console.
I have gone through many solutions but no success yet.

Some useful snippets:

[image: Pipeline code]

[image: Job logs]

Comment: The way you call it seems correct to me. Could you try replacing the powershell script with something simple like ls?

Comment: @smelm when i do ls inline e.g **powershell script: 'ls'** it gives me expected output but when executing ls from file, nothing prints on console.

Comment: I have almost the same problem: it works outside of the script but not within the script!

Comment: This solution worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/42576572